# How to get the last query executed in Laravel 5.3?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

I try like this :

```
public function displayList()
{
    \DB::enableQueryLog();  
    $query = Self::orderBy('program_code')->orderBy('output_code')
                 ->orderBy('account_code')->all();
    dd(\DB::getQueryLog());
    return $query;
}
```

The result is like this :

```
[]
```

It displays an empty array

Is there anyone can help me?

Comment: Have you ever tried Debugbar for Laravel?

Comment: @KmasterYC, Never before

Comment: You could listen to laravel db queries as I've mentioned bellow

Answer (score 4):

Most suitable way to go about this is listen to db queries. You can do

```
\DB::listen(function ($query) {
    dump($query->sql);
    dump($query->bindings);
    dump($query->time);
})
```

in your route file. this will dump out executing db queries. But if you want a much cleaner approach you could wrap above listener inside laravel logger like this.

```
\Log::info(
    \DB::listen(function ($query) {
        dump($query->sql);
        dump($query->bindings);
        dump($query->time);
    })
);
```

then the output will be dump into `your-app/storage/logs/laravel.log`.

NOTE: Keep in mind to remove or comment out above codes as they are for development purpose only.

Further, you could put it in `AppServiceProvider` like it is mentioned in [database transactions](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/database#database-transactions)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use the package Laravel debugbar: https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar. It shows you list of queries executed, and other useful data you want to see.